# Обновить DataSource для DataGridViewComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть DataGridView (c# winforms vs2010 net4.0), в который добавляется строка (по одной):

```
private void btn_AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = dGV.Rows.Count;
            index++;
            dGV.Rows.Add();

            int nRowIndex = dGV.Rows.Count - 1;

            string[] ListGroups = listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell Col1 = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dGV.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[0];
            Col1.DataSource = ListGroups;
        }
```

К колонке1 (Col1) привязывается список ListGroups, который формируется на основе списка контрола listBox1.
В колонке1 выбрано значение. Далее я меняю (код btn_Groups_Click) содержимое списка listBox1 (например, удаляю значение-строку которая выбрана в колонке1). В результате происходит ошибка.

```
    private void btn_Groups_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form4 frm4 = new Form4();
                if (frm4.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string[] ListGroups = frm4.ListBox2.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
                    listBox1.Items.Clear();
                    listBox1.Items.AddRange(ListGroups);

                    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column1 = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dGV.Columns[0];
                    column1.DataSource = null;
                    column1.DataSource = ListGroups;
                }

                frm4.Close();
                frm4.Dispose();
            }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в таком случае удалить (возможно с оповещением пользователя что такое-то значение уже отсутствует) из колонки1 уже отсутствующее значение и выполнить перепривязку к измененному listBox1?

Comment: Какая именно ошибка происходит? Я попытался воспроизвести ваш код - работает странно, но никакой ошибки нет.

Answer (score 0):

Это не ответ, потому что в вопросе недостаточно данных для него. Надеюсь, постепенно мы к нему придём.

Пока я проведу небольшой код-ревью.

В первом методе у вас есть неиспользуемая переменная `index`. Она создаётся, инкрементируется, но далее не используется. Можно выкинуть?

Метод `DataGridView.Rows.Add()` возвращает индекс добавленной строки. Логично использовать его:

```
int index = dGV.Rows.Add() - 1;
```

---

Нейминг. Он ужасен. Смотрите [Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)

`ListGroups` - переменные именуются в виде camelCase: `listGroups`.
`Col1` - это же `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` - ячейка, а не колонка. Я бы назвал `cell`.
`listBox1` - о чём говорит эта цифра 1? Ни о чём. Дайте говорящее название, что-то вроде `listBoxGroups` или что там у вас в этом листбоксе.

`btn_AddRow` - нормальное название: "Добавить строку", можно оставить.
`btn_Groups` - не совсем понятно, что именно делает кнопка: показывает (show), редактирует (edit), удаляет (delete/remove)? Имя должно это отражать.

`Form4`, `frm4` - аналогично, что значит 4? Судя по коду, там идёт работа с какими-то группами. `FormGroups` или `GroupEditingForm` (форма редактирования групп), не?

`column1` - я бы назвал её либо просто `column`, либо добавил суть: `columnGroup` и т. п.

---

В одних местах у вас используется привязка данных: `DataSource = ...`, в других местах работа напрямую с контролом: `Items.OfType`, `Items.AddRange`.
Правильнее было бы завести коллекцию, в которой хранятся данные. И эту коллекцию использовать и для привязки данных к GUI-контролам, и для передачи в другие методы/формы.
Удаление/добавление элементов тоже делается в этой коллеции - благодаря привязке данных изменения будут автоматически отображаться в GUI.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваши комментарии. Подскажите пожалуйста, сейчас в ячейки DataGridView добавляю данные (из файла mdb) используя DataSource, как использовать коллекции и привязывать их к ячейкам DataGridView? Можете дать ссылки где почитать или примеры.